# Migration react-router v5 to v6 dynamic tab navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I've got some problems upatading to react router v6 within my common component with tab navigation.

The url looks like:

- domain.com/home/:tab
- domain.com/settings/:tab

I've got a base route like home, settings,...
At the end, the name of the tab is added:

```
 tabs={[
      {
        label: t("navigations.firsttab"),
        path: "firsttab",
      },
      {
        label: t("navigations.secondtab"),
        path: "secondtab",
      },
    ]}
```

This results in:

- domain.com/home/firsttab

My working code of the shared component (tabs) in v5:

```
const history = useHistory();
  const { classes } = useStyles();
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent, newValue: string) => {
    history.push(newValue);
  };
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <>
      <Tabs
        className={classes.tabContainer}
        centered={alignCenter}
        disableripple={`${disableRipple}`}
        indicatorColor={underlineColor}
        onChange={handleChange}
        orientation={orientation}
        scrollButtons="auto"
        textColor={tabTextColor}
        value={history.location.pathname}
        variant={tabVariant}
        {...tabContainerProps}
      >
        {tabs.length > 0
          ? tabs.map((item) => {
              return (
                <Tab
                  classes={{
                    selected: classes.tabSelected,
                    root: classes.tabRoot,
                    // button: classes.tab,
                    wrapper: classes.tabLabel,
                    wrapped: classes.tabLabel,
                  }}
                  disableRipple={disableRipple}
                  icon={item.icon}
                  key={item.path}
                  label={item.label}
                  {...tabProps}
                  wrapped={wrapTabLabel}
                  value={`${url}${item.path}`}
                />
              );
            })
          : null}
      </Tabs>
```

My code in v6:

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const { classes } = useStyles();
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent, newValue: string) => {
    navigate(newValue);
  };
  const url = location.pathname; //not the same like useRouteMatch and therfore not working... I don't find the solution regarding useMatch 
  return (
    <>
      <Tabs
        className={classes.tabContainer}
        centered={alignCenter}
        disableripple={`${disableRipple}`}
        indicatorColor={underlineColor}
        onChange={handleChange}
        orientation={orientation}
        scrollButtons="auto"
        textColor={tabTextColor}
        value={location.pathname}
        variant={tabVariant}
        {...tabContainerProps}
      >
        {tabs.length > 0
          ? tabs.map((item) => {
              return (
                <Tab
                  classes={{
                    selected: classes.tabSelected,
                    root: classes.tabRoot,
                    // button: classes.tab,
                    wrapper: classes.tabLabel,
                    wrapped: classes.tabLabel,
                  }}
                  disableRipple={disableRipple}
                  icon={item.icon}
                  key={item.path}
                  label={item.label}
                  {...tabProps}
                  wrapped={wrapTabLabel}
                  value={`${url}${item.path}`} //I do not find a solution to get the url like useRouteMatch() does. item.path is the subpath of the tab, e.g. firsttab (domain.com/home/firsttab)
                />
              );
            })
          : null}
      </Tabs>
```

How can I resolve the url like useRouteMatch?

Comment: Did you try `useMatch()`? According to the official guide [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#replace-useroutematch-with-usematch) you should _replace useRouteMatch with useMatch_.

Answer (score 1):

`react-router-dom` v6 is capable of using relative routing, this is why the `useMatch` hook isn't a one-to-one replacement to the v5 `useRouteMatch` hook.

You don't need to grab the `url` prefix to do the navigation, `navigate` can handle navigating relatively to sibling routes. So long as the sibling `path` values are unique, it can work as a tab value.

```
tabs={[
  {
    label: t("navigations.firsttab"),
    path: "firsttab",
  },
  {
    label: t("navigations.secondtab"),
    path: "secondtab",
  },
]}
```

...

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { classes } = useStyles();
const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent, newValue: string) => {
  navigate(newValue); // "/home/firsttab" <-> "/home/secondtab"
};

return (
  <>
    <Tabs
      ...
      onChange={handleChange}
      ...
    >
      {tabs.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Tab
            ...
            value={`../${item.path}`} // "/home/firsttab" <-> "/home/secondtab"
          />
        );
      })}
    </Tabs>
  </>
);
```